# Using regular Python generator in Tornado coroutine

Tags: python, generator, tornado, coroutine

The Python generator is a great feature. It allows me to encode complex, possibly recursive traversal logic and decouple it from its user. Usually I use it like this code below

```
TREE = {
  1: [2,3],
  2: [],
  3: [4,5],
  4: [6],
  5: [],
  6: []
  }   

def query_children(node):
    return TREE[node]

def walk_tree(root):
    # recursive tree traversal logic
    yield root
    children = query_children(root)
    for child in children:
        for node in walk_tree(child):
            yield node

def do_something():
   # nice linear iterator
   for node in walk_tree(root):
       print(node)
```

Tornado is using generator is implement coroutine, which is also great way to build asynchronous function without callback.

However I can confused when trying to use both together.

```
@gen.coroutine
def query_children(node):
    ...
    raise gen.Return(children)


def walk_tree(root):
    # recursive tree traversal logic
    yield root
    children = yield query_children(root)
    for child in children:
        for node in walk_tree(child):
            yield node


def do_something():
   # nice linear iterator
   for node in walk_tree(root):
       print(node)
```

In the new walk_tree, the first yield is the regular Python yield. The second yield is Tornado's. Can they both work together?

Comment: I'm wondering didn't you forget to consume the generator in the 5th line `walk_tree(child)` ? You only create generator object but don't use it. You have to add one more loop:

```for node in walk_tree(child):
    yield node
```

Comment: Edited to make the code runnable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python generator protocol is based on *synchronous* interfaces; it is not possible to use *asynchronous* code like a coroutine as a part of a generator to be used with `for` (the most important rule of coroutines: anything that calls a coroutine must also be a coroutine, or at least aware of coroutines. The `for` statement doesn't know anything about them, and it is what calls your generator). Instead, I suggest using a `tornado.queues.Queue`:

```
@gen.coroutine
def query_children(node):
    ...
    raise gen.Return(children)


def walk_tree(queue, root):
    # recursive tree traversal logic
    yield root
    children = yield query_children(root)
    for child in children:
        for node in walk_tree(child):
            yield queue.put(node)
     yield queue.put(None)


def do_something():
    queue = tornado.queues.Queue()
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(walk_tree, queue, root)
    while True:
        node = yield queue.get()
        if node is None:
            break
        print(node)
```

Comment: Unfortunately to use Queue add significant amount of overhead to `do_something()` compares to for loop over a generator :( Mark Queue as accepted answer unless there are other suggestions.

Comment: The other possibility would be to add a `callback` argument to `walk_tree`, and call the callback for each node instead of yielding it or putting it on a queue. This is the fastest option available, although it can sometimes be awkward to structure things as callbacks.

Comment: Can I regard `Queue(1)` as a asynchronous generator or a pipeline? Is there any problem to use `Queue(1)` to export 100000+ documents from motor [fetch_next](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_cursor.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCursor.fetch_next)?

Comment: I wouldn't say that a queue *is* a pipeline, but you can definitely *build* a pipeline using a queue. If you have 100k+ documents, a `Queue(1)` probably won't perform as well as one with a larger buffer, but it will still work.

Comment: @WaiYipTung when you said "significant amount of overhead" - in terms of what? running time? code complexity?

Answer (score 0):

I get this working. Instead of using yield in the non-coroutine `walk_tree()`, I run it synchronously using get the children by calling `IOLoop.run_sync`. I am a Tornado novice. So please comment if this is a legit solution or if there is any other better way.

```
TREE = {
  1: [2,3],
  2: [],
  3: [4,5],
  4: [6],
  5: [],
  6: []
  }   

@gen.coroutine
def query_children_async(node):
    raise gen.Return(TREE[node])

# this is a regular Python generator
def walk_tree(root):
    # recursive tree traversal logic
    yield root
    # call .result() of the Future
    children = IOLoop.instance().run_sync(lambda: query_children_async(root))
    for child in children:
        for node in walk_tree(child):
            yield node

@gen.coroutine
def do_something(root):
    # just collect the result
    result = [node for node in walk_tree(root)]
    raise gen.Return(result)
```

> Edit 1. The original proposal using `.result()` does not work. I got
>   "DummyFuture does not support blocking for results" when I have a
>   non-trivial `query_children_async()`.

Comment: Replace the filed `.result()` with `IOLoop.instance().run_sync`.

Comment: It is not safe to call `run_sync` from inside another coroutine. The IOLoop should be started *once*, with either `run_sync` or `start`, at the top level of your file, and then left to run for the duration of the program.

Comment: Any insight if there is any hope in using `.result()`?

Comment: No. In Tornado `.result()` is only useful in conjunction with `.add_done_callback()` and is rarely used explicitly (normally it's called by `yield`)